# Protect Windows Applications against password recovery tools

Tags: c#, winforms, security

I am developing a c# application where a user will enter some informations like server, database, user and password (the password is hidden `this.txtPassword.PasswordChar = '*';`), if I use a password recovery tool like [BulletsPassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bullets_password_view.html) it reveals the password while I know some applications are protected from this tool (skype, yahoo messenger, ...).

I want to know what I must do to protect my application

Answer (score 4):

**Workaround:** quote from the site you linked:

> This utility works fine with most password text-boxes, but there are some applications that don't store the password behind the bullets, in order to increase their security. In such cases, BulletsPassView will not be able to reveal the password.

which means that you might be able to protect yourself by getting the actual password out from the PasswordBox and replacing it with dummy characters **on every keystroke**.

**Better Approach:** Use [**Current, Relevant Technology**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as opposed to archaic winforms:

I just tested with a [WPF `PasswordBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.aspx) and it is not detected/revealed by the BulletsPassView tool.

Comment: I use a simple textBox in Winform indeed, a solution in Winform projects will be very helpful

Comment: +1 for use WPF (appropriate technology). Winforms is true ancient. Nothing new should be using it (with some very specific exceptions)

Comment: Seeing your profile, it is clear for me now that is not a good idea trying to discuss about choosing technologies with such a huge fan of one in particular. I took the liberty of editing the answer to remove my vote, feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: @yms thanks.. but it's not a matter of being "fan". It's a matter of winforms being absolutely retarded and useless with absolutely zero features, and WPF, while it has actual issues, is at least a decent usable framework with actual features.

Answer (score 2):

If your computer is compromised than no amount of obfuscation and tricks([Skype tricks](https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-europe-06/bh-eu-06-biondi/bh-eu-06-biondi-up.pdf)) can help you against the determined attacker - your app will have to use password(or other secret information) in its clear form(it may be hashed, encrypted, does not matter - in the end it will be in the same form used for the authentication). Modern user operating systems are not designed to protect you against the belligerent administrator or compromised core.

I think that you should not worry about the disclosure of your password in the PasswordBox control - if some one is able to do something similar on your machine than he is able to do something much worse. That is not the threat anybody can effectively deal with in such the circumstances.

The only real way to protect your password(or secret key) is ... to not store it in your app at all and use it only on secure trusted computers for the shortest amount of time possible, removing and clearing all the info after.

**EDIT(after comments):**

With such amount of ready made tools and exploits you should not underestimate the script kiddies.

If you want to protect Windows.Forms.PasswordBox from BulletsPassView-like tools than you should name your question accordingly(if it is your goal then rename it - your question will be less broad with very determined goal).

*About actual protection for PasswordBox:*

As I suppose BulletsPassView just accesses targeted windows  through hooks(like [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)) and gets needed values([Spy++ hooks internals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/01/16/spy-internals.aspx)).

If you want protection against BulletsPassView you could try some non-standard PasswordBox or use another UI. But I am not sure that it will really solve the problem for eternity.

There is not much you could actually [do](http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/sakdat/ht05/assignments/pm/programme/DLL_hooks.pdf) against hooks that I know of. As I've already said the main protection is the environment that restricts everything not allowed and runs everything with the least privileges. You can't protect your system against everything - create some formal finite threat model and implement features needed to deal with the identified threats.

P.S.: I am not very knowledgeable in dll hooks - may be someone knows a way.
P.P.S.: And do not forget to rename the question to reflect your actual goals and problems.

Comment: But it stills a solution against script kiddies and neophytes hackers, I just want to know the secret (how to) of this solution in winforms